# How do i only read the second word from the .txt file

Tags: c++, string, fstream

I want to read and extract the actors Surname from opened text file.

I tried to do it like this, but It could only read every other word from the sentences.

The Actors surname ends with a semicolon but I don`t know how to proceed.

(I don't want to use vectors as I don't fully understand them)

```
bool check=false;

while (!check) //while false
{
    string ActorSurname = PromptString("Please enter the surname of the actor:");


    while (getline (SecondFile,line)) //got the line. in a loop so keeps doing it 
    {
        istringstream SeperatedWords(line);  //seperate word from white spaces
        string WhiteSpacesDontExist;
        string lastname;

            while (SeperatedWords >> WhiteSpacesDontExist >> lastname) //read every word in the line //Should be only second word of every line
            {
                //cout<<lastname<<endl;
                ToLower(WhiteSpacesDontExist);

                if (lastname == ActorSurname.c_str()) 

                {
                    check = true;
                }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand your problem? please explain !
you said you opened .txt file and want to read surname of actors but you did not say where is surname`s position in every line!!!

Comment: my only problem is that i want to figure out how to only read the 2nd word of every line in the text file but i cant seem to figure it out. the 2nd word of every line also happens to always end with a semi colon if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each line of your file contain two words separated with space (and second word ends with semicolon), below is example how you can read second word from such `string`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string text = "John Smith;"; // In your case, 'text' will contain your getline() result
    int beginPos = text.find(' ', 0) + 1; // +1 because we don't want to read space character
    std::string secondWord;
    if(beginPos) secondWord = text.substr(beginPos, text.size() - beginPos - 1); // -1 because we don't want to read semicolon
    std::cout << secondWord;
}
```

Output:

```
Smith
```

In this example, we use method `find` of `std::string` class. This method returns position of character we look for (or `-1` if character wasn't found), which we can use to determine begin index required in `substr` method.

Comment: @HaidyE I've simplified this solution a little bit :)